# React Native: If I'm using `npx react-native`, what happens in version in package.json is not most recent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, package.json, npx

In my React Native project, I'm using `npx react-native run-ios`, which I know uses the latest version of `react-native`, but I don't have the latest version in my package.json. As of now, the version in my package.json is 0.62.0, and the latest version is 0.63.4

**What I Want to Know:**

1. What will version 0.62.0 be used for, and what will 0.63.4 be used for?
2. Is it a problem that I have these two different versions? I know that upgrading the version in package.json can break the app.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `npx react-native run-ios` means - `npx` will check the whether the package exists in your local project binaries.

If yes, it will execute it.

Else you can mention a version of the library to execute `npx react-native@0.62.0 run-ios`

Comment: Are the local project binaries the ones referenced in package.json? In other words, since my package.json has 0.62.0, npx would use 0.62.0 rather than the latest (0.63.4)?